# How to work on different interdependent maven modules in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project A that depends on another maven project B. So in the pom of project A there is dependency element that refers to a version of project B. I use IntelliJ, as my IDE and now I want to make changes in project B like add a new method and I want this method to be available immediately in project A. But because project B is a different maven project. I have to make the changes in B and then do a mvn install so that the jar gets created in my local repository before those changes be available for project A. I tried creating a project from existing sources for project A and then 'Import Module from Existing Sources' for project B so that all source code for project A and B are in the same IntelliJ window but this doesn't work. How can I setup IntelliJ such that I have project A refer the source code for project B in the same IntelliJ window rather than going to the local maven repository?

Comment: Sounds like those projects belong into a multi module build....

Comment: In Eclipse, this is called Workspace Resolution. I guess IntelliJ does not have such a thing.